# How to write correctly <%= t('.title_#{Time.now.wday}') %>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

Usually to add a word (for my multilanguage website) I use this system: `<%= t('.title') %>`
Now in `config/locales/en.yml`, I added something like this:

```
en:
  home:
    title: Title
    title_0: Finally Sunday! Watch this title
    title_1: Hey! It's monday! This is the Title
```

And I want to use Time.now.wday and to create something like `<%= t('.title_#{Time.now.wday}') %>`

But it doesn't work. **How to write it correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need double quotes for string interpolation in Ruby. Just replace

```
<%= t('.title_#{Time.now.wday}') %>
```

for

```
<%= t(".title_#{Time.now.wday}") %>
```

although it maybe should be

```
<%= t("home.title_#{Time.now.wday}") %>
```

because `title`, `title_0` and `title_1` are nested under `home`

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation does not work with single quotes
That means that:

```
puts "Works in double quoted strings: #{1 + 2}."
puts 'Not not work in single quoted strings: #{1 + 2}.'
```

will print out:

```
"Works in double quoted strings: 3."
"Does not work in single quoted strings: #{1 + 2}."
```

source: http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html